# Where can I find file latex.‎tex?

Tags: latex-base, file-lookup

Where can I find file latex.‎tex?‎ I don't have it in my tex ‎distribution‎. I‎ ‎have ‎only ‎file ‎latex.ltx ‎on ‎my ‎system.
By the way, I'm using Texlive 2010.

Comment: Why do you think a latex.tex should exist? latex.ltx is the right file which contains the latex code.

Comment: Why do you need to find such a file?

Comment: I think `latex.ltx` was once called `latex.tex`; in LaTeX2 or maybe even earlier. I remember to have read at least one mentioning of it.

Comment: @Raphink: I want to redefine the \chapter* command. I was told that I can find its definition in file latex.tex. I have found the definition of \chapter command in file book.cls, but I could not find the definition of \chapter*.

Comment: @araz: `\chapter*` is not a command. It's a `\chapter` with a `*` afterwards. The definition of `\chapter` checks (using `\secdef`) if a `*` follows and calls `\@chapter` or `\@schapter` depending on the result. This is an example of the `\@ifstar` mechanism that allows star versions of commands.

Comment: @araz: you probably don't really want to redefine `\chapter` or any of the related commands. Most of the time, people just want to redefine how a chapter heading is formatted or similar. You may want to post a more specific question if that sort of thing is your ultimate goal.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't exist on standard distributions.  Try asking `kpsewhich latex.ltx` at the command prompt; the directory that file is in contains the files that make up the heart of Latex.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to look at latex.ltx and don't want to worry about messing up your system, you can look at the version here:

[mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)

I assume this should be good enough if your system is reasonably up to date.